# Get elements of array based on their length

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Say I have an array filled with two letter words all the way up to fifteen letter words.  How would one get only three letter words from the array?

```
a = ['aa', 'ab', 'ad', ... , 'zoogeographical']
b = []
a.each do |x|
    if x.length = 3
        b.push(x)
    end
end
```

Seems like there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `select` method is what you are looking for:

```
 a.select {|string| string.length == 3 }
```